# Python loop through list of tuples

Tags: python, list, loops, tuples

I have the following function:

```
def buyLotsOfFruit(orderlist):
    totalCost = 0.0
    for fruit in orderlist:
        if fruit not in fruitPrices:
            return None
        else:
            totalCost = totalCost+fruitPrices.get(fruit)*pound
            return totalCost
```

where:

```
fruitPrices = {'apples': 2.00, 'oranges': 1.50, 'pears': 1.75,
           'limes': 0.75, 'strawberries': 1.00}
```

let's say I have the following orderlist:

```
orderlist = [('apples', 2), ('pears', 3), ('limes', 4)]
```

the looping keep returning none when I wants it to look in the fruitPrices list and check if all the item exist it will calculate the total price. for listed items otherwise if one is missing will return none

Note: that pound is the integer in the tuples list associated for each fruit in the orderlist.

Comment: Did you mean: ‘if fruit[0] not in fruitPrices:’?

Comment: Yes, if any of the fruits isn't listed in fruit price it will return none other wise it will take the price from fruitPrices and multiply it with how many pound of that fruit

Comment: Surely your code has an error due to pound? You should include it in your question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Think your code have to be something like this, depending on your logic.

```
def buyLotsOfFruit(orderlist):
    totalCost = 0.0
    for fruit, pound in orderlist:
        if fruit not in fruitPrices:
            return None
        else:
            totalCost = totalCost+fruitPrices.get(fruit, 0)*pound
    return totalCost
```

Comment: Doing this it only return the total price for the first item. In our example the apple 2*2 = 4. it doesn't continue looping through the other items.

Comment: Doing this I guess you will get a total price from fruits mentioned in orderList.

Comment: @Abdullah It actually does loop through everything. Double check your results. It returns the total price of 2 apples, 3 pears, and 4 limes.

Comment: it worked now I had the return inside the else forgot to take it out